# Do smooth compact connected manifolds admit CW compositions with a single 0-cell?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I have stated this question incorrectly before, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is true, what bout closed interval $[0,1]$, it is certainly a smooth manifold, and as you can prove it cannot have one $0-cell$.

This result is true for closed smooth manifold, because you can find a Morse function on it with one minimum, i.e a critical point of index $0$. And then it corresponds to the $0-cell$ of the CW-presentation of that manifold. (Now if you consider the dual presentation, then this actually proves that a closed smooth manifold has a CW-structure with exactly one $n-cell$, where $n=dim$ of the manifold).